# To Convert C# published code and in to proper solution file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one c# Application which i have only published Application in IIS and i don't have the original code with me.

we have to make some changes in one (.cs) file which is dependent on entire application and dlls.

Is it possible to convert the Application and make some changes and publish again.

Answer (score 0):

I did run into this situation before where client is only having published code and I need to enhance a product.

For those , I decompiled published DLLs using Telerik's [JustDecompile](https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) as I found it more mature and accurate than DotPeek and Reflector.

Few of the things will still not work after decompilation and that is obvious so you will need to manually fix those.

You may also remove few of the layers by introducing your own layer to avoid all DLL decompilation , but for that you need to understand decompiled code.

I hope that it will help you in running project.

Thanks,